# drupal how to get "confirmation to administrator for editing the article by any other user"... Wikitools

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I need the Administrator Aproval to be displayed when any user edits article(node)
Confirmation Will be done after Administrator Aproval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use maestro module and maestro initiator module to create a workflow which will get triggered when user apply for confirmation . then it goes to desired person which you will assign when you initiate the maestro workflow. there you can give accep and reject option to the admin and after admin click any button you can perform your desired work.